# get file from subproject

Tags: java, maven

I need to load a text file that's inside a sub project (managed by Maven). This subproject has no classes in it.
The packaging of my main project is war, while the packing of the subproject is jar.

The structure looks like this:

```
mainproject (war packaging)
  src
    main
      java
        MyClass.java (this will try to load TheFileINeed.txt)
  subproject (jar packaging)
    textfiles
      TheFileINeed.txt
```

How can I access those files?

Comment: you want to access file in java class or where ?

Comment: I need to reference a file from a Java class, but the file is in a sub project

Comment: You coukd try either adding sub project as dependency or use remote resourxr plugin

Comment: I did try adding it as a dependency, but then how it's referenced?

Comment: 1. file that you are attempting to access should be in classpath 2. now you can read the file from classpath using Resource `getClass().getResource("/relative/path/to/your/resource.txt");`

Comment: Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("") returns app/target/classes, but the jar is in app/target/app/WEB-INF/lib. So how can the file be retrieved?

Comment: just give relative path to your resource in classpath it should be able to pickup